# User input Matrix in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, matrix, nasm

I am new to assembly language and for some code i need to get a user specified matrix .
How to  take in 2D array  in NASM assembly language . 
Thanks :)

we can specify the number of rows and col like this

```
 .DATA
   NO_ROWS EQU 5
   NO_COL EQU 3
```

Comment: Do you know how to get a single input? If not, start with figuring that out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 2D array in assembly language, because the memory is always 1D. (The HLL arrays use the technique described below).

You have to allocate `NO_ROWS x NO_COL x ELEMENT_SIZE` bytes of memory using the NASM data definition directives.

Then if you need the `element(I,J)` you need to compute the offset in the array as

```
OFFSET = NO_COLS x ELEMENT_SIZE x J + ELEMENT_SIZE x I
```

Now the address of the needed element is:

```
address = ARRAY_START_ADDRESS + OFFSET
```